# Insert text string into ido minibuffer using non-interactive defun

Tags: emacs, ido, minibuffer

Need to insert some text in the ido mini-buffer during ido-find-file using a defun bound to a key chord.  This behavior is the same as if the following sequence was typed interactively, C-x C-f, followed by C-e to edit the mini-buffer, followed by deleting the current text then typing or yanking the text that I want to insert.  To that end I have run this defun and just after ido-find-file:

```
(global-set-key [f10] 'mytest)

(defun mytest ()
  (interactive)
  (ido-edit-input) ;#1
  (delete-minibuffer-contents) ;#2
  (insert "C:/users/family/" )) ;#3
```

My expectation is that the mini-buffer would contain the given string (#3) after one invocation of mytest.  However it seems as if I need to run mytest 2x to get the inserted string into the mini-buffer.  After the first invocation the ido mini-buffer is in edit mode, however is as if only the #1 was run (the original text is still present).  After the 2nd invocation of mytest the ido mini-buffer seems as if #1, #2 and #3 have been executed.

I am using a stand-alone mini-buffer which is part of the one-on-one library.
Running GNU emacs 24.4 on Windows.

Here is my custom configuration of ido, which I run at emacs startup.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;IDO Config
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
;
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-everywhere 1)
;
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode 1)
;
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1)
;
;https://github.com/gempesaw/ido-vertical-mode.el/blob/master/ido-vertical-mode.el
;; Display ido results vertically, rather than horizontally
  (setq ido-decorations (quote ("\n-> " "" "\n   " "\n   ..." "[" "]" " [No match]" " [Matched]" " [Not readable]" " [Too big]" " [Confirm]")))  
(defun ido-disable-line-trucation () 
(set (make-local-variable 'truncate-lines) nil))
(add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook 'ido-disable-line-trucation)
;
 (setq ido-ignore-buffers '("\\` " "^\*Mess" "^\*Back" ".*Completion" 
"^\*Ido" "^\*trace" "^\*compilation" "^\*GTAGS" "^\*Help" "^session\.*" "^\*"))
;
;use IDO for more things
(setq recentf-max-saved-items 100)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I have confirmed that the logic is somewhat sound by binding the individual commands then running them interactively.  It seems as if running the same defs from lisp is acting differently than running the same interactively.

Ido-edit-input is C-e during ido-find-file

```
(global-set-key [f11] 'delete-minibuffer-contents)
(global-set-key [f12] (lambda () (interactive) (insert "C:/users/family")))
```

Also tried inserting (sit-for 1) in the mytest defun on the possibility that there is some timing issue.

How can the defun mytest be modified to insert a string (#3) with a single invocation?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer to the question in the title, but it does do what you apparently want:

```
(defun my-ido-find-file-in-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory "C:/users/family"))
    (call-interactively 'ido-find-file)))

(global-set-key [f10] 'my-ido-find-file-in-dir)
```